# Best methodology to compare computed phylogeny tree with taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, phylogenetics, trees, network

I have computed a phylogenetic tree using an alignement of sequences, and I would like to :

1. Compare it to the "known" taxonomy (uniprot/ncbi which I know is not
   the most up to date one) and extract a metric of how "divergent" it
   is.
2. [Optional] Visualize the differences (I can probably come up with a
   solution for that one, but if someone knows of a nice tool to do so
   ?)

What are the best metrics / tools / methodologies to do such a comparison ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `ape` package in R. It has a function called `cophyloplot` which allows you to visualize two trees like so:

[image]

Which is well described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285542/plot-phylogenetic-trees-face-to-face-with-links-in-r) question (also the source of the image).

There is also the `dist.topo` function which produces a metric which describes the topological distance between two phylogenetic trees. I don't know if this is what you mean by "divergent" but I hope it helps.